# How to programmatically get sites list and virtual dirs in IIS 7?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

Does anybody know how to programmatically get the sites list and virtual dirs in IIS 7?

Comment: Is this still an issue? If not mark one of the below as an answer.

Answer (score 70):

Check out this post - seems to be a brand-spanking new management API in the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosag/microsoft-web-administration-in-iis-7)

Here's a quick graphical overview from that blog post:

[image]
<sub>(source: [carlosag.net](https://www.carlosag.net/images/ServerManager.png))</sub>

And here's a "The Gu" post on [Cool new IIS7 Features and APIs](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/443513)

Something like this will find all the sites, their application and their virtual directories in your IIS7 server:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();

        foreach(Site s in mgr.Sites)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Site {0}", s.Name);

            foreach(Application app in s.Applications)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tApplication: {0}", app.Path);

                foreach(VirtualDirectory virtDir in app.VirtualDirectories)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tVirtual Dir: {0}", virtDir.Path);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: The best way to thank Marc would be to accept his excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you for the additional code example. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

One important caveat to using the Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly is the code has to be running on a machine that has IIS7 installed.

When I was developing a system to load IIS7 sites into a webpage on my windows XP machine I discovered this limitation.  The API is great, I just wished I could have used it.

[Control IIS 7 server from Windows 2003 server programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504016/control-iis-7-server-from-windows-2003-server-programmatically/4337120#comment-8969022)