# How to get the application names hosted in IIS?

Tags: c#-4.0, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have an application which is used to configure the applications under "Default Web Site" in IIS. Now i want to check whether all the applications are hosted in IIS successfully or not using C# code. Can anyone please guide me to get the application hosted name from IIS?

I have tried but no luck.

Thanks in advance!!!

Regards,
Karthi.

Comment: Got solution from the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555668/how-to-programmatically-get-sites-list-and-virtual-dirs-in-iis-7

Answer (score 0):

```
new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/w3svc").Children
```

Comment: Any dlls needs to be add as reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on IIS 7 and above, you can use Microsoft.Web.Administration,

http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/extending-the-management-ui/overview-of-mwa-and-mwm-for-iis

Besides, keep in mind the facts you should know,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/05/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know/